# listBox not displaying content until program is recompiled c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm able to display items in a listbox which are filenames from a directory. Newly added items are not displaying until the program is recompiled. I've tried "ListBox.Refresh()", but it didn't work. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
     InitializeComponentDirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".\\Notes\\");
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
         listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with _Newly added items_? Are these new items new files created externally from your program in the Notes folder?

Comment: The program reads in a .TXT file and copies that .TXT file to the Notes directory.   The Listbox displays the contents of the Notes directory...  (hope that makes sense)..

Comment: When do you run InitializeComponentDirectoryInfo?

Comment: I think you may be looking for the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You should monitor your directory and when a file is added you can add it to your listbox.

Answer (score 1):

The ListBox (and in general your program) have no way to know if you add new files to the Notes directory. This info is known only to the File System. Luckily the NET Framework allows your program to be notified of these events using a class named [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)....

This is an example how to implements some kind of monitoring on a system folder using an instance of the FileSystemWatcher class

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();

void Main()
{
    FileSystemWatcher f = new FileSystemWatcher(@"d:\temp");
    f.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;    
    f.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);    
    f.EnableRaisingEvents = true;  

    Form fm = new Form();
    lb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(f.Path))
        lb.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    fm.Controls.Add(lb);
    fm.ShowDialog();
}


private void watcher_Created(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    string newFile = e.Name;
    if(!lb.Items.Contains(newFile))
        lb.Items.Add(newFile);

}
```

Note that I have made some changes to your original code. If you don't need a full FileSystemInfo class then there is no need to employ this class but the simpler Directory class is enough to retrieve the file names. Then the loop is constructed using the EnumerateFiles class that allows your code to fill the listbox without filling before an array of files.

(IE you can test this code using LinqPad, do not try to run it as is on Visual Studio, it will not work)